# Unable to convert color code to brush color for cell-border in WPF table

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I have the hex code for the color I need but am unable to convert and apply it to the my brush for coloring the border of a table's cell. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
                tc = (TableCell)sender;
                Color greenShade = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00");
                BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
                BorderBrush brush = converter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00") as Brush;
                tc.BorderBrush = brush;
```

**Error**:
System.Windows.Controls.Control.BorderBrush' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

This code doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
BorderBrush brush = converter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00") as Brush;
```

to

```
Brush brush = converter.ConvertFromString("#FF66CC00") as Brush;
```

`BorderBrush` is a property in `System.Windows.Controls.Control` but you have used as a `Type`